# How should the notify wait mechanism of Java be called?

Tags: java, concurrency

What is an appropriate name? I read notify/wait should barely used for anything else, but building **condition queues**. Another possible name might be **thread coordination**. In the [Java concurrency tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html) its named **Guarded Blocks**. Actually I find no one of these suitable. Is there a better keyword to describe this mechanism?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That would be a [Monitor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monitor_%28synchronization%29)

Answer (score 2):

Thread coordination seems reasonable. The wait/notify methods coordinate via the object's monitor. [Monitor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monitor_%28synchronization%29) is maybe the concept you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Doug Lea factored Object's monitor (synchronized) and the wait/notify mechanisms into the [Lock](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html) and [Condition](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html) interfaces respectively.

These support richer and more fine-grained functionality than Object's monitor, but are explicitly providing the same functionality.

Calling wait/notify Condition is fairly standard.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5875437/convert-wait-notifyall-code-to-use-java-1-5-lock-object/) for some usage details on Locks/Condition